# Prolog Card Game: Valid sets

Tags: list, prolog

I am working on a simple card game, which involves laying cards on the table in particular groups. I would like to write a predicate which tries to find out whether a set of cards can be arranged into valid groups.

Cards in a valid group must exclusively either:
a) of the same suit, and of consecutive numbers (hearts 1,2,3) or 
b) of different suits and the same number (1 of hearts, 1 of diamonds and 1 of clubs)
The smallest allowable group is three.

Step one is to define what the cards are, and the obvious approach is to define them in predicate form:

```
%hearts:
card(1,h).
card(2,h).
% etc.....

%diamonds:
card(1,d).
card(2,d).
%etc...
```

and so on for the clubs and spades.

Secondly I have defined a series of predicates to specify the rules. How cards can connect, and how to test for a valid group. For example I have defined the following to check whether two cards are valid and have the same suit and the same number:

```
card_will_connect((N1,S1),(N2,S2)):-
    %firstly check that the cards exist:
    card(N1,S1),
    card(N2,S2),
    %same_suit
    S1=S2,
        consecutive_number(S1,S2).
```

I have also written some predicates that run through a group of cards to see whether the connections between them are valid.

The problem is, if I have a random set of cards - how do I try to group them in valid ways without exhaustive searching?

My idea to approach this is:
a) find out if any of the cards have zero possible connections within the set. If so fail and don't continue
b) find out if any cards have only 1 valid connection, move these to groups
c) now with the remaining cards, try to allocate them to these groups by using my card connection predicates to meet the required rules

Comment: Not very clear how you want your predicate to work. Does it have as a first argument the cards, and as the second argument the groups?

Comment: `S1=S2, consecutive_number(S1,S2)` is weird. If S1 and S2 are equal, they can't be consecutive. Did you mean `consecutive_number(N1,N2)` ?

Comment: Yes that's correct Thomas, I meant to say I call the predicate with the card numbers to check them.

Comment: Yes, the predicate I am trying to write would have two arguments. The first argument as the list of cards to be grouped, and the second a list of valid groups (list of lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sort the sequences, and would use built ins like findall/3 and append/2. Then a validation predicate is easier to write:

```
% build a bridge deck
bridge_deck(Cs) :-
    findall(card(S,V), (member(S,[♥,♦,♣,♠]),between(1,13,V)), Cs).

% shuffle
bridge_hands([S,W,N,E]) :-
    bridge_deck(Cs),
%setrand(rand(1,2,3)), % get a known random set, to ease debugging
    random_permutation(Cs, RCs),
    maplist([H]>>length(H,13), [S,W,N,E]),
    append([S,W,N,E], RCs).

% behaves like a bridge player :)
hands_sorted(Sorted) :-
    bridge_hands(Hands),
    maplist(sort, Hands, Sorted).

group_hand(Hand, Groups) :-
    findall([A,B,C|D],
      (append([_,[A,B,C|D],_],Hand), 'same suit and consecutive numbers'([B,C|D],A)), Groups).

'same suit and consecutive numbers'([card(S,Y)|R], card(S,X)) :-
    succ(X,Y),
    'same suit and consecutive numbers'(R, card(S,Y)).
'same suit and consecutive numbers'([], _).

?- hands_sorted(Ps), maplist(group_hand, Ps, Gs), maplist(writeln, Gs).
Ps = [[card('♠', 1), card('♠', 4), card('♠', 5), card('♠', 11), card('♣', 2), card('♣', 4), card('♣', 10), card(..., ...)|...], [card('♠', 2), card('♠', 6), card('♠', 9), card('♠', 12), ...
Gs = [[], [], [[card('♥', 10), card('♥', 11), card('♥', 12)], [card('♥', 10), card('♥', 11), card('♥', 12), card(..., ...)], [card('♥', 11), card('♥', 12), card(..., ...)]], []].
```

I used a more appropriate representation for the bridge logic: card(Suit,Value)

*edit*

SWI-Prolog has a nice structured output facility. This snippet layouts a bridge table in readable shape:

```
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).

bridge_cards :-
    hands_sorted(Hands),
    layout_table(Hands).

layout_table([S,W,N,E]) :-
    phrase(html([\css,
     table([
        tr([\empty,     \layout_hand(N),    \empty]),
        tr([\layout_hand(W),    \empty,     \layout_hand(E)]),
        tr([\empty,     \layout_hand(S),    \empty])
    ])]), Tokens),
    with_output_to(atom(X), print_html(Tokens)),
    win_html_write(X).

css --> html(style(type='text/css',
    ['.size{background-color:lightgrey;}'
    ,'.player{color:blue;}'
    ,'.value{text-align:right;background-color:lightgreen}'
    ])).

empty --> html(td([class=size],[])).

layout_hand(Cards) -->
    {findall(S-Vs, (
        member(S, [♣,♦,♥,♠]),
        findall(V, member(card(S,V),Cards), Vs)
    ), SuitesValues)},
    html(td([class=player], table(\layout_suits(SuitesValues)))).

layout_suits([]) --> [].
layout_suits([Suit-Values|SVs]) -->
    html(tr([td(Suit), \layout_values(Values)])),
    layout_suits(SVs).

layout_values([]) --> [].
layout_values([V|Vs]) --> html(td([class=value], \layout_value(V))), layout_values(Vs).

layout_value(V) --> {nth1(V,['A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'T','J','Q','K'],C)}, html(C).
```

I think that getting output in HTML is particularly handy, since it allows to experiment with minimal fuss and later - if required - porting the code to SWI-Prolog HTTP server, to run in the wild.

Example running from [swipl-win](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-swipl-win), with HTML rendering handled by Qt:

[image]